# Value of count() divided by a number

Tags: r, count

I want to divide the result of count() by a number. E.g. if result of `count()` is 30, I want to divide it by a number, say 5:

```
count(x)/5
```

R code:

```
count(data, "p_code"=" ")
```

where data is data frame name, p_code is the column I want to count number of objects.
I'm getting the following error:

> "Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: I am guessing `count` is from the package `dplyr`?

Comment: Yes it is from dplyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` returns a column 'n' that gives the frequency of the column specified.  Assuming that we want to get the frequency of column 'pcode', then there would be two columns in the output, i.e' 'pcode' and 'n'.  To divide by 3, it should divide the column 'n' instead of the whole dataset (pcode can also be non-numeric)

```
library(dplyr)
count(data, pcode) %>% 
    mutate(n = n/3)
```